# Should a purchase be acknowledge again subscription renewal?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm implementing google in-app billing on my app. Normally, when a subscription reaches expire time, it will be automatically renewed. A new purchase is made ([with the purchase token remain the same](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview#purchase-tokens-and-order-ids))

So, should my app acknowledge this new purchase or can I safely ignore it?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Apps don't have to "acknowledge" subscription purchases, unless you mean telling the user, "Thanks for buying!". Apps will need some way of testing for the presence of a current, valid subscription before they provide certain services, to defend against fraud. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

after rereading the google play in app billing documentation (https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_releases_notes#2_0_acknowledge)

"For subscriptions, you must acknowledge any purchase that has a new purchase token. This means that all initial purchases, plan changes, and re-signups need to be acknowledged, but you do not need to acknowledge subsequent renewals. To determine if a purchase needs acknowledgment, you can check the acknowledgement field in the purchase."

so basically, if the subscription is renewed, i don't have to acknowledge it.
i share the answer here for anyone interested in the same topic.

Answer (score 0):

You simply periodically call `billingClient.queryPurchases()` if you use the billing libray, or `mService.getPurchases()` if using the AIDL

If the user has renewed the subscription, it will return that the user owns the item, if he decides not to renew it, after the grace period, if any, it will return that he does not own the item.